# Why is my regex not working using sed in bash script on Mac OSX?

Tags: bash, sed, osx, regular-expression

I am trying to capture `CBX-1234` from the string `CBX-1234--CBX-5678` or `CBX-12345--CBX-5678`. I am using a bash script on Mac OSX using sed to run the regular expression.

```
string="CBX-1234--CBX-5678"
shortenedString=$(echo "$string" | sed "s/^([A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+)/\1/")
```

This outputs the following error message:

> sed: 1: "s/^([A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+)/\1/": \1 not defined in the RE

How can I capture the substring? I am open to suggestions using sed or other means in bash.

Comment: Tried `sed -E "s/^([A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+)/\1/"` and it didn't work :( Outputs this error: `": \1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: (1) That command really should work.  Maybe there’s a bug in OS X’s version of ``sed``.  (2) Please [edit] your question to report things you’ve tried that didn’t work.  (But don’t do that when you get it working; just accept the correct answer.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add `-E` to the `sed` command line to make it use extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+)/\1/'
```

If what you want to do is to shorten the string `CBX-1234--CBX-5678` to `CBX-1234`, you additionally need to modify the substitution to take the whole string into account:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

You may alternatively use the `bash` parameter expansion

```
shortenedString="${string%%--*}"
```

This will remove everything from `$string` from the first occurrence of `--`.

Comment: Just want to emphasise that without `-E`, **sed regexes on Mac are really broken** - basic things like `?` and `\1` don't work, because the default is compatibility with the ancient `ed` editor (1970s vintage).  Even `man re_match` describes the default as 'obsolete regexes' - so really 'extended regexes' are just 'sane regexes'.

Comment: @RichVel Sorry, but you are wrong. Without the _non-standard_ `-E` option, `sed` uses basic regular expressions. The extended regular expression modifier `?` is written as `\{,1\}` and `\1` work if your capture group looks like `\( ... \)`. Basic regular expressions have not been obsoleted, are not "broken", and are explained by the POSIX standard here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion, but for me a regex that cannot include `?` for zero or one matches is broken, and it's very common to run into sed commands that require this or `\1`.  POSIX compliant regexes are described as 'obsolete regexes' in `re_match` man page and I agree with that term.  I write scripts that work on common Linux systems, rather than trying to restrict myself to POSIX which is a subset of typically used features.

Comment: @RichVel Sorry, but I just saw your comment from 3 years ago and just wanted to point out that extended regular expressions, enabled in `sed` with `-E`, are also POSIX regular expressions. The POSIX standard defines both basic and extended regular expressions. As I wrote in an earlier comment, `?` is just syntactic sugar for `\{,1\}`.  POSIX extended regular expressions do not support capture groups and `\1`, `\2` etc. as in `(.)\1+` (unless you use non-standard GNU tools) whereas the basic regular expression `\(.\)\1\{1,\}` is supported by all POSIX regex tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo "$string" | cut -d "-" -f 1,2`.

Comment: You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., ``"$string"``) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  By contrast, you don’t really need you quote the dash (**``-``**), although, of course, it doesn’t hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I always use `sed -r`

```
$ echo "abhellocd" | sed -r "s/.*(hello).*/\1/g"
hello
```

From the man page of sed:

```
   -r, --regexp-extended
          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

The option `-E` isn't listed by me. Although it works too.

Comment: question is related to macOs, where sed command is slightly different.. `-r`is not recognized, the equivalent is `-E`